# If $A \cong C$ and $B \cong D$, then $A \times B \cong C \times D$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ are groups. If $A \cong C$ and $B \cong D$, then $A \times B \cong C \times D$.

Is the statement true?

Comment: What kind of objects are $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$?

Comment: What are $A,B,C,D$, and what is $\cong$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, on the hypotheses, there is some nice map from $A$ to $C$, and some nice map from $B$ to $D$, and then you can put those two maps together to get a nice map from $A\times B$ to $C\times D$.

Comment: Ah, groups! OK, given isomorphisms from $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $D$, can you see how to construct an isomorphism between the products?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Let $\phi_A: A \to C$ be an isomorphism and let $\phi_B: B \to D$ be an isomorphism. Define $\phi : (A \times B) \to (C \times D)$ by $\phi(x,y) = (\phi_A(x),\phi_B(y)) $. We check that this is an isomorphism. Clearly it is onto, and if $\phi(a,b) = \phi(x,y)$ then $\phi_A(a) = \phi_A(x)$ so $a = x$ since $\phi_A$ is an isomorphism, and you see that the second coordinates are the same in the same way, so $\phi$ is injective aswell. To see that this is a homomorphism take $\phi((a,b)(x,y))$. Then $\phi((a,b)(x,y)) = \phi(ax,by) = (\phi_A(ax),\phi_B(by)) = (\phi_A(a)\phi_A(x),\phi_B(b)\phi_B(y))$ Which is equal to $(\phi_A(a),\phi_B(b)) (\phi_a(x),\phi_B(y)) = \phi(a,b) \phi(x,y)$.

Hence $\phi$ is a bijective homomorphism, thus $A \times B \cong C \times D$ as we wanted to show.

Comment: Presumably, you wanted $\phi_B$ to go from $B$ to $D$.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Fixed it now.